# How to interrupt or chain a transition based on the active transition

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, transition

I have a plot of SVG circles with some filter controls as checkboxes. The circles have an enter transition (filter is checked - come into screen), an exit transition (filter is unchecked - leave screen), and an update transition (filter is hovered over - highlight element).

Since I'm using the same control to enter/exit/highlight (i.e. a checkbox), whenever I uncheck a filter and then move the mouse away, the highlight transition cancels the exit transition and the circle sticks around in whatever position it was on its way out.

Is there a way to chain the highlight transition so that it doesn't cancel the exit transition? And is there a way to label the transitions so that I can chain or interrupt based on the label of the active transition? I don't think I could use the `transition.each` or `transition.transition` methods because the elements selected by the exit transition may not be the same as those selected by the highlight transition (e.g. user clicks on filter1 then hovers over filter2).

To be explicit, the end goal is

- If active transition is enter/exit

  - If subsequent transition is enter/exit, interrupt and apply
  - If subsequent transition is highlight, chain
- If active transition is highlight

  - If subsequent transition is highlight, interrupt and apply
  - If subsequent transition is enter/exit, chain

This can be boiled down to

- If subsequent transition is same as active transition, interrupt and apply
- If subsequent transition is not same as active transition, chain

Hovering over a button highlights various circles and clicking on it removes them. Try clicking and moving the mouse away to see the problem.

```js
// Setup container
var container = d3.selectAll('#svgContainer');
var width = 640,
    height = 480;
var nShapes = 50;

// Create random data
var filteredData,
    data = d3.range(nShapes).map(function(d, i) {
        return {
            id: i,
            x: Math.floor(Math.random() * width),
            y: Math.floor(Math.random() * height),
            r: Math.floor(Math.random() * width / 15),
            red: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
            blue: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)
        };
    });

// Create filter functions
var filters = {
    red: function(d) {return d.red > 50;},
    blue: function(d) {return d.blue > 50;}
};

// Create SVG
var svg = container.append('svg')
    .attr({
        width: width,
        height: height
    });

// Hook up hover handlers for filters
$(".filter").hover(function(e) {return onHover(e, this.dataset['filter']);});

// Hook up click handlers for filters
$(".filter").change(function(e) {
    filterData();
    draw();
});

// Filter data and draw the canvas
filterData();
draw();





/**
 * Recalcualte filtered data
 */
function filterData() {
    filteredData = data;
    
    $('.filter').each(function(idx, el) {
        var filterName = this.dataset['filter'];
        var filteredOut = !$(this).find("input").prop('checked');
        if (filteredOut) filteredData = filteredData.filter(function(d) {
            return !filters[filterName](d);
        });
    });
}

/**
 * Hover handler
 */
function onHover(event, filterName) {
    var isHovering = (event.type == "mouseenter");
    svg.selectAll('.shape')
        .filter(filters[filterName])
        .transition().duration(100)
        .attr({
            r: function (d) {return isHovering ? 1.5 * d.r : d.r;}
        })
        .style({
            opacity: isHovering ? 0.5 : 1.0
        });
}

/**
 * Draw function
 */
function draw() {
    var duration = 750;
    var shapes = svg.selectAll('.shape').data(filteredData, function(d) {
        return d.id;
    });
    shapes.enter().append('circle') // apply to enter selection only
        .attr('class', 'shape')
        .attr({
            cx: 0,
            cy: 0,
            r: 0
        })
        .style('fill', 'white');

    shapes.transition().duration(duration) // apply to enter + update selection
        .delay(function(d) {return (d.id / nShapes) * duration;})
        .attr({
            cx: function(d) {return d.x;},
            cy: function(d) {return d.y;},
            r: function(d) {return d.r;}
        })
        .style({
            fill: function(d) {
                if (filters.red(d) && filters.blue(d)) return "purple";
                if (filters.red(d)) return "red";
                if (filters.blue(d)) return "blue";
                return "green";
            }
        });

    shapes.exit().transition().duration(duration) // apply to exit selection only
        .delay(function(d) {return (d.id / nShapes) * duration;})
        .attr({
            cx: 0,
            cy: 0,
            r: 0
        })
        .style('fill', 'white')
        .remove();
}
```

```css
svg {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.shape {
    fill-opacity: 0.9;
}
label {
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="red" class="filter" data-filter="red">
    <input type="checkbox" checked />Red Filter</label>
<label id="blue" class="filter" data-filter="blue">
    <input type="checkbox" checked />Blue Filter</label>
<div id="svgContainer"></div>
```

Comment: In D3, scheduling a new transition always cancels existing transitions. You could however check if there's a transition on the element already (check for the `.__transition__` attribute in the data) and not schedule a new transition if this is the case.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I had actually tried this before but it didn't work out. There were situations where the highlight transition on `mouseleave` would _not_ interrupt the highlight transition on `mouseenter` and the circles would stay highlighted. This is because I can't check _which_ transition is active (i.e. I want to interrupt the transition if the previous one is highlighting but not if it's entering/exiting).

Comment: Well there can only be one transition active at a given time, so I'm not entirely sure what you're saying. Do you mean that you had several transitions working at the same time?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I edited the question to be a bit more explicit about the end goal (I also updated the snippet to include an enter transition and better visualization of filters).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. I would store an attribute with the data denoting the type of the current transition that you can check to see whether you should cancel it later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:** There's a new "named transition" d3 API being [proposed](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/pull/2084). I was able to [test this out](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/65y7nb8c/67/) and it works great! Much simpler than the hacking below!

---

I was able to find a solution, but it's quite complicated ;( Hoping someone will take a look at this and post a much simpler solution =) I also opened up a [d3 issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/2076) with more details.

To reiterate, the final goal is

> - If subsequent transition is same as previous transition, interrupt and apply
> - If subsequent transition is not same as previous transition, chain

This ideal behavior can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/65y7nb8c/). I essentially replace a standard `.transition()` call with a `.call(transitionHandler)`. The `transitionHandler` function looks like

```
/**
 * Transition handler
 * @param selection the selection object
 * @param label the transition namespace
 * @param duration the transition duration
 * @param apply a function that applies transition attributes/styles
 * @param remove true if removing the element at end of transition
 */
 function trans(selection, label, duration, apply, remove) {
    selection.each(function(d) {
        // Create new transition if no current transition/selection
        if (!this.__transition__ || !transitionSelections[d.id]) {
            transitionSelections[d.id] = d3.select(this).transition();
            var newTransId = transitionSelections[d.id].id;
            this.__transition__[newTransId].namespace = label;
        }
        else {
            var transId = this.__transition__.active;
            var transition = this.__transition__[transId];

            // If the transition hasn't started yet, grab the next one
            if (!transition) {
                var transIds = Object.keys(this.__transition__)
                    .filter(function(el) {
                        // Only keep transition IDs (and not 'active' or 'count' keys)
                        return !isNaN(el);
                    })
                    .sort(function(a,b) {
                        // Convert to numbers and sort
                        return +a - +b;
                    });

                // Find the next transition
                var idx = d3.bisect(transIds, transId);

                // Sometimes, the transition object doesn't exist yet?!
                if (idx == transIds.length) transition = null;
                else {
                    transId = transIds[idx];
                    transition = this.__transition__[transId];
                }
            }

            // If the label matches (or the object doesn't exist yet), interrupt and start new transition
            if (!transition || transition.namespace == label) {
                transitionSelections[d.id] = d3.select(this).transition();
                var newTransId = transitionSelections[d.id].id;
                this.__transition__[newTransId].namespace = label;
            }
            // Otherwise chain it
            else {
                transitionSelections[d.id] = transitionSelections[d.id].transition();
                var newTransId = transitionSelections[d.id].id;
                this.__transition__[newTransId].namespace = label;
            }
        }

        // Apply transition attributes
        // FIXME: linear easing for debugging only
        transitionSelections[d.id].ease('linear').duration(duration).call(apply).each("end", function(d) {
            if(remove) d3.select(this).remove();
        });
    });
}
```

I use `transitionSelections` as a dictionary to keep track of the latest selection transition so that I can chain transitions when I need to. I also tack on a `namespace` property to the `__transition__[id]` object and use that label to decide whether to interrupt the transition or chain it.